# Why the function save in my controller does not work?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am doing a simple crud with springboot and thymeleaf but when i try to do the update or create with the function save I lose the data of the object. I click on the buttons new and update I open the modal correctly with the data with the object charged but when i click in save i loss the object.

**I believe that my problem is in the form and I do not know what it is. I have tried with postman and I do not receive a request when I click on save or update**

index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script th:src="@{js/main.js}" src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Paginación con SpringBoot</h1>
        </div>  
        <button class="btn btn-success nBtn">New</button>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>COUNTRY</th>
                            <th>CAPITAL</th>
                            <th>ACTION</th>
                        </tr>   
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="country :${data.content}">
                            <td th:text="${country.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${country.name}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${country.capital}"></td>
                            <td>
                                <a th:href="@{/delete/(id=${country.id})}" class="btn btn-danger dBtn">Delete</a>
                                <a th:href="@{/findOne/(id=${country.id})}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item" th:each="i :${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)}">
                        <a th:href="@{/(page=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link" th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'active':''"></a>
                    </li>   
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="myForm">
     <form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${country}" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or Create</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id" class="col-form-label">Id:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" th:value="*{''}" disabled/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" th:value="*{''}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="capital" class="col-form-label">Capital:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capital" name="capital" th:value="*{''}"/>
                  </div>                      
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Save"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              <p class="alert alert-danger">Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="delRef">Delete</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

controller :

```
        @Controller
public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) {
        model.addAttribute("data", countryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,4)));
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(Country country) {
        countryRepository.save(country);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteCountry(Integer id) {
        countryRepository.deleteById(id);;
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/findOne")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Country> FindOne(Integer id) {
        return  countryRepository.findById(id);


    }
}
```

js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text=='Edit'){
        $.get(href,function(country,status){
            $('.myForm #id').val(country.id);
            $('.myForm #name').val(country.name);
            $('.myForm #capital').val(country.capital);
        });
        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }else{
        $('.myForm #id').val('');
        $('.myForm #name').val('');
        $('.myForm #capital').val('');
        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }
});
$('.table .dBtn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myModal #delRef').attr('href',href);
    $('#myModal').modal();
});});
```

class:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String capital;


    public Country(String name, String capital) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public Country() {
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", capital=" + capital + "]";
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
    public void setCapital(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }
}
```

repository:

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country,Integer>{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly missing the @RequestBody annotation on the save method

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(@RequestBody Country country) {
    countryRepository.save(country);
    return "redirect:/";
}}
```

Comment: hi, and thanks but i try to use this and i continue whithout answer. i do not get that the program save me the data.

Comment: Post the request header and body, or the curl

Comment: I do not understand very well what you need. I have published the form with its action and its method, which it sends to the controller, which is where I should store the data, it is a small application.

Comment: the three files are complete

Comment: don´t make the post, i think that i have all well

Answer (score 1):

- @RequestBody as mentioned already.
- Provide your country class code
- What is the code for CountryRepository?
- If you put a break point in your controller save method do you actually get country data or is it null?

As an aside you shouldn't be hitting your repository from your controller as there is no transaction management.

Comment: my problem is that the form don´t post request y i don´t know why

Answer (score 1):

Use `@RequestBody` and `repository.saveAndFlush(entity)`

By using `@RequestBody` annotation you will get your values mapped with    the model you created in your system for handling any specific call

On `saveAndFlush`, changes will be flushed to `DB immediately` in this command. With save, this is not necessarily true and might stay just in memory, until flush or commit commands are issued.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(@RequestBody Country country) {
        countryRepository.saveAndFlush(country);
        return "redirect:/";    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[@mantamusica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7708486/mantamusica) if you are still interested in, I have a solution for you.

[@Jason Portnoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272188/jason-portnoy) [@Patel Romil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10961238/patel-romil)

In this exact case, add annotations
`@RequestBody` returns error code 415.

The solution to this problem lies on the HTML side, or rather Bootstrap.

Just delete

`data-dismiss="modal"`

from input

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="save"/>
  </div>
```

... and it works for me :)